# .forEach() vs .stream.forEach()?

Tags: java, foreach, stream

I've been learning how to use streams and lambda expressions, and came across this question.

What is the difference between:

```
Arrays.asList(myDogs).forEach((d) -> {System.out.println(d.toString());
                                            actAsDog(d);});
```

and this:

```
Arrays.asList(myDogs).stream().forEach((d) -> {System.out.println(d.toString());
                                                    actAsDog(d);});
```

They both produce the exact same result, one by making a stream of the list and the other by using an iterator. Is there any other differences that I don't know about, and is one better than the other?

Comment: Don't forget `Stream.of(myDogs).forEach`!

Comment: Well, if `asList().forEach()` makes an iterator instead of a stream then that would be the difference, right?  However streams and iterators are different (and there should be some large differences, if you look) then that's the answer.

Comment: Why use `Arrays.asList(myDogs).stream()` instead of `Arrays.stream(myDogs)`?

Comment: Because you can't use .stream() on arrays.

Comment: Take a look at this article (especially page 2). You will find the differences between your methods and benchmarks as well. 
 
http://www.javaworld.com/article/2461744/java-language/iterating-over-collections-in-java-8.html

Comment: @zephos2014 I know, but I proposed `Arrays.stream(myDogs)`, **not** `myDogs.stream()`.

Comment: Oh yeah. I see that now. Thank you. Didn't know about that method.